# AJAX error handling

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jquery, error-handling

I searched for a good overview of AJAX error handling, but alas could not find what I was looking for.

My main question is about parameters. It seems the standard signature is something like:

```
errorHandler(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
```

I understand what it all means, but when I tried it out, all I get is the first param. The other two are undefined. The first param, looks like this:

```
{
    [Methods] : {...},
    [prototype] : {...},
    errors : [Error retrieving data],
    errorThrown : "custom error",
    sender : {...},
    status : "customerror",
    xhr : null
}
```

The error handler is setup like this:

```
var myWidget = new Widget({
    error: errorHandler,
    moreStuff: ...
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I am using the error handler like this

```
$.get('some.aspx',
        function(data) {

        }).error(function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(XMLHttpRequest.status, ',', textStatus, ',', errorThrown);
        });
```

[For more information](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: I'm not a fan of this notation and you didn't really answer my question. Do you have working code that uses a 3 param version of the error handler ?

Comment: I am working with this single param only, three parameter also will work in this ex:`error(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)` second one `textStatus` will give you the description, third one is  `errorThrown` receives the textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found" or "Internal Server Error."

Comment: @AnalogKid17 is it addressed your question?

Comment: thanks for your answer, but that does not work for me. I am using Kendo UI controls and I am limited to the notation described above.